# Ridge.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'normalize'

Tags: deep-learning

Why does Ridge from sklearn.linear_model not have a normarize keyword argument?

It cross-validates Ridge, which does have normarize. Should this keyword not be passed on? Or am I missing something here?

```
# === ridge test ===

from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
import numpy as np

n_samples, n_features = 10, 5
np.random.seed(0)
y = np.random.randn(n_samples)
X = np.random.randn(n_samples, n_features)

clf = Ridge(alpha=1, copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, max_iter=None, normalize=False,random_state=None, solver='auto', tol=0.001)

clf.fit(X, y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sklearn Ridge model does not accept the 'normalize' keyword in the parameter list. That's why you are receiving this error. For more information on the list of accepted parameters, you can check the Sklearn documentation:
[Sklearn Ridge model](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.html)